# Self-documenting bash one-liner

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a possibility to put a bash command (or series of commands) that produces an output file, completely to the same output file, i.e.

```
echo foo bar | awk '{print $1}' > outfile ; <some magic>
```

so `outfile` content should look like

```
foo
# echo foo bar | awk '{print $1}' > outfile ; <some magic>
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: `cp foo bar` seems to fit your criteria...

Answer (score 0):

Is this an acceptable solution?:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ script -a outfile -c /bin/sh
Script started, file is outfile
$ echo foo bar | awk '{print $1}'
foo
$ 
Script done, file is outfile
```

Then check the contents of `outfile`:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ cat outfile 
Script started on 2018-08-01 03:03:56-0500
$ echo foo bar | awk '{print $1}'
foo
$ 

Script done on 2018-08-01 03:04:05-0500
```